# Correctly commit to database using @Transactional in spring-data

Tags: jpa, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, mockito

I have a test function, that should perform the following task

1. insert data to db
2. query db and verify data is as expected

The problem is that in my test, the data has not been committed to the db, like it's stuck in some `transactional` step, how can I surely commit the data before the second query is executed.

This is a part of my test function, `@Rollback(false)` is just for development phase.

```
@Test
@Rollback(false)
....
reportJobManager.saveOutput(savedDef, pipeline, results, null)
reportJobManager.retryRetention(savedDef, listOf(csvDeliverbale))
```

saveOutput func. sample code

```
@Transactional
fun saveOutput() {
    if (deliverable.type.name == "DATA_RETENTION_RESULT") {
        finishedPipeline.postProcessors.forEach {
            //it(definition, dbDeliverable)
            val dbRetention = ReportRetention(
                deliverable = dbDeliverable,
                definition = definition,
                retryCount = 1L
            )
            val retentionUploadSaved = retentionRepository.save(dbRetention)
            if (retentionUploadSaved.id == null) {
                throw IllegalStateException("Retention upload was not saved!")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`retryRetention` func code

```
fun retryRetention(definition: ReportDefinition, listOfDeliverables: List<Deliverable>) {
        retentionRepository.findAll().forEach {
            if (it.state.name == "NOT_UPLOADED" && it.retryCount!!.toInt() < 5) {
                if (it.deliverable?.success == true) {
                    it.state = RetentionUploadStatus.UPLOADED
                    println("RetentionUploadStatus->UPLOADED")
                } else {
                    val schemaService = SchemaServiceImpl()
                    val schemas = schemaService.initializeSchemas(definition, emptyMap())
                    val parameters = definition.parameterPolicy.policy(schemas.parametersSchema)
                    val delivery = deliveryPolicyService.policy<Deliverable>(ValidDeliveryPolicy.RETENTION_ONLY, schemas.deliverySchema)
                    val deliveryFunction = delivery.createDeliveryStep()
                    deliveryFunction(parameters, listOfDeliverables)
                    it.retryCount = it.retryCount!!.plus(1L)
                }
                retentionRepository.save(it)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Too brief code is provided. Learn about [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a method `saveOutput()` with `@Transactional` annotation, you need to add `@Transactional` above every other method that is calling `saveOutput()` for the transaction to actually commit.